# How to Filter Linux Command output with python re module?

Tags: python

I have written the following program for detecting the RAID type. When I am running the following script, the `re` module is not matching the string and always giving me `Raid Type not found` output.

```
import subprocess
import re

RAIDTYPE = subprocess.Popen('lspci -mm |grep -i "RAID bus controller"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output=RAIDTYPE.communicate()[0]

matchObj = re.match(r'(.*) MegaRAID (.*?) .*', output, re.M|re.I)
matchObj1 = re.match(r'(.*) 3ware (.*?) .*', output, re.M|re.I)

if matchObj:
    print("This is MegaRAID")
elif matchObj1:
    print("This is 3Ware Raid")
else:
    print("Raid Type not found")
```

Comment: can you print output and check what is coming as a result of `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: Are you sure the regex is correct? I would just do something like `re.match(r'.*MegaRAID.*', output, re.M|re.I)`

Comment: @arno_v Thanks, It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the regex is not correct. This should work:

`re.match(r'.*MegaRAID.*', output, re.M|re.I)`